# A closed ideal in $L^1(T)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be the unit circle and consider the convolution group algebra $L^1(\mathbb{T})$.  Let $I_n$ be the closed ideal generated by the polynomial $p_n(z)=z^n-1$ in $L^1(\mathbb{T})$.
Let $I=\bigcap_{n\geq1}I_n$.

> Q. What is the character space of the quotient $\frac{L^1(\mathbb{T})}{I}$?

Comment: I think $I$ is just the constant functions. The dual of $L^1$ is $\mathbb Z$ and the dual of $L^1({\mathbb T})/I$ is ${\mathbb Z}\smallsetminus \{0\}$. The projection $L^1\to L^1/I$ dualises to the inclusion.

Comment: @Echo why only constant functions? Take an open set $A\subset \mathbb{T}$ which contains all roots of unity but measure of $A$ is less than 1. Any summable function supported outside $A$ belongs to $I$.

Comment: We are talking about convolution here. Note that $z^n*z^m$ is zero if $n\ne m$ and equals $z^n$ if $n=m$. This means that the ideal generated by $p_n$, $n\ne 0$, is 2-dimensional. It is spanned by $1$ and $z^n$.

Comment: I need to ask just to make sure if I get the notation right: is $I_n=\{f*g_n: f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})\}$ where $g_n(t) = p_n(e^{2\pi i t}) = e^{2\pi i nt} - 1$ ?

Comment: @OnurOktay,  Yes, you are right. Indeed we have that,  $f*g_n(s)=\int_{\mathbb{T}}f(t)g_n(t-s)dt=\langle f, e_n\rangle e_n -\int f(t)dt$ where $e_n(s)=e^{2\pi ins}$.

Comment: Well, in that case, $f\in I_n$ iff $\hat{f}(k) = 0$ for all $k\notin\{0,n\}$. So $f\in I$ iff $\hat{f}(k) = 0$ for all $k\neq 0$ iff $f$ is constant. Here $(\hat{f}(n))_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ denote the Fourier series coefficients of $f\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$.
Second, every character $\tilde{h}$ of $L^1(\mathbb{T})/I$ is of the form $\tilde{h}(f+I)=h(f)$ for some character $h$ of $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ such that $I\subset\ker{h}$. Consequently, the character space of $L^1(\mathbb{T})/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$.